# Numpy maskedarray missing stack function

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, numpy

I'm using Numpy 1.12.1.

According to the documentation for [vstack](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ma.vstack.html)

> This function continues to be supported for backward compatibility, but you should prefer np.concatenate or np.stack. The np.stack function was added in NumPy 1.10.

But there is no `numpy.ma.stack` function. The `np.stack` function does not function correctly when trying to stack masked arrays.

Should I continue using `numpy.ma.vstack` or is there another way to achieve the same functionality without relying on a seemingly deprecated function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that deprecation statement overstates the usefulness of `stack`.  No one is going to stop using `vstack` or `hstack`. But these are all front ends of `concatenate`.  I encourage everyone to look at the source code for these functions to see how they manipulate dimensions prior to using `concatenate.

I see stack as more of a generalization of `np.array`.  When given a list of 2d arrays, `np.array` joins them on a new axis at the front, producing a 3d array.  `np.stack` lets you join them on 2 other new axes.

`np.stack` can replace `vstack` when given a list of 1d arrays. but not if given a mix of 1 and 2d.

`Masked arrays` at a bit of backwater, and don't get new features as quickly.  Use the functions it provides, and don't worry about the `stack` docs.

---

`ma.vstack` does (where `func= np.vstack):

```
    _d = func(tuple([np.asarray(a) for a in x]), *args, **params)
    _m = func(tuple([getmaskarray(a) for a in x]), *args, **params)
    return masked_array(_d, mask=_m)
```

It does a `vstack` on the `.data` and `mask` parts, and then creates a new masked array.   Looks like it could easily be extended to work with `np.stack`.

Comment: Thanks. For what it's worth, `np.ma.vstack` didn't do what I was expecting either. I had a list of 2d masked arrays that I just wanted stacked on top of each other to create one big 3d array. `ma.vstack` ended up stacking along the existing dimension, when what I actually wanted was a new dimension. I ended up using `np.ma.array(my_list_of_2d_arrays)` and it works great.